# Step Counter App like pedometer in android

Tags: android

I want to do work with the pedometer technique for getting total steps of user when he/she move from one place to another.As i did googling and i found that "FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER" worked with nexus 5 but i want that this technique should be worked with all devices.For this i also applied Sensor (TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) and after that i shake device without move from one place to another but sensor increment step counter so i notice that it should not be right.
Your suggestion would be appreciate.Thanks in advance

Comment: and with code, make question readable with formatting ; refer : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

- As both **sensors** `FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER` are hardware dependent **Nexus** devices are first devices which are supporting them so you can check them by **hasSystemFeature**
- THanks!